# How to use the Table.SplitColumn while also keeping the original column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a column with first and last name, which are always just two names with a space between them.

I'd like to have 2 new columns with **First name** and **Last name** but I still like to **keep** the original **Full name** column:

Original data:

| Full name |
| --- |
| John Doe |

I'd like to get instead:

| Full name | First name | Last name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | John | Doe |

The usual command is:

```
= Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Full name", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"First name", "Last name"})
```

But it loses the original column. Is there a way to do it without losing the original column?

Comment: Duplicate the column, then split the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applied the steps as seen on the image below:

1. Duplicate the column
2. Split the new (duplicate) column.
3. Rename the columns

[image]

This will be the result:
[image]